# How to use my Github-Account on my PC instead of some other account?

Tags: git, github

In the following picture, you can see that I created a repository on http://github.com. This "commit" is connected with my Github account (exactly what I want).

[image]

But then, I used the terminal on my MacBook and made a commit, but in this case, this commit is connected with my real first- and last name.

In my Terminal:

```
git push origin master
```

I was asked then:

```
Username for 'https://github.com'
```

and

```
Password for 'https://my-nickname@github.com
```

I answered those questions but the commits were created by this account with my real name...

How can I use my Github Account on my PC instead of this other account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your github account can have different information than your local repository.
The mail you use in your git config must also be in your github account (https://github.com/settings/emails)

Look your git user name and your user email with :

```
$ git config user.email
$ git config user.name
```

Look the user name and the mail use by your github account

```
$ git log
```

You have to configure your name and your mail for you local repository.

```
$ git config --global user.name "John Doe"
$ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
// global is for all your local git repository
```

more information https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup

You can see the git configuration file `~/.gitconfig`